# Can not access object in laravel and has "0" indexes when appliying toArray()

Tags: arrays, object, laravel, eloquent

I have these tables

clientes

> id
>   nombre_rz
>   ced_rif
>   telefono
>   id_usuario

solicitantes

> id
>   nombre
>   email
>   telefono
>   id_cliente

```
cliente->hasMany('solicitante')<br>
solicitante->belongsTo('cliente')<br>
```

^ This is well written in the models, just trying not to make a wall of text.

After Authenticating, when i do

```
$cliente = Cliente::where('usuario_id','=',Auth::id())->with('solicitante')->get();
                    dd($cliente);
```

or

```
$cliente = Cliente::where('usuario_id','=',Auth::id())->with(array('solicitante' => function($query)
            {
                $query->where('cliente_id', '=', '35');

            }))->get();
            dd($cliente);
```

i get this obect 
[Object from query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iodom.png)

And using toArray() i get this

[Array from object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cneg.png)

And if access index 0 of that array like

```
$array = $cliente->toArray(); dd($array['0']);
```

i get

[Index 0 of array][3]

As far as i can see the queries are correct, and the data i need is there, but i don't know why i can't access the object like

```
$cliente->id; $cliente->telefono, $cliente->solicitante->nombre, $cliente->solicitante->email
```

It always throws

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$telefono

Can't Understand this behavior.

Comment: This is the last image http://i.stack.imgur.com/veeAu.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning an array of objects, because you asked Laravel for a group. You can either do

```
foreach ($cliente as $client)
{
     echo $client->telefono;
     foreach ($client->solicitante as $solicitante)
     {
         $solicitante->nombre;
     }
}
```

OR you can specify that you only want one result

```
$cliente = Cliente::where('usuario_id','=',Auth::id())->with('solicitante')->first();
echo $cliente->telefono;
foreach ($client->solicitante as $solicitante)
{
    $solicitante->nombre;
}
```